# Apple watch: Creating mail app style rows in WKInterfaceTable

Tags: watchkit, ios8.2, wkinterfacetable

I would like to be able to create rows for a **WKInterfaceTable** that, once the user **slides them from right to left**, show an extra control (like it happens with the mail app in the Apple Watch).

Here is an image of the Mail app (please refer to the top left and bottom left image):

http://core0.staticworld.net/images/article/2015/04/applewatch_mail-100581468-medium.idge.jpg

Any idea on how they did it?

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not possible for normal third-party developers. WatchKit just does not offer this. Refer to the WatchKit Framework Reference, which is available [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WatchKit_framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014968).

Apple may allow native watch applications (offering more options) later this year.  Maybe we will know more already next month (WWDC).

**Is a custom control possible that mimics that behavior?**

I see two problems:

- Your WatchKit code does not run on the watch but on the iPhone (it's an extension). Even if you could implement some custom control that can change its position, it may be very choppy because of the BT connection. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/DesigningaWatchKitApp.html).
- Also, you would have to be able to detect the location of the finger. I don't know about a WatchKit method that gives you this information.

Comment: Is there any official documentation saying that is not possible to do so? Could you add a reference to your answer?

Comment: Thanks. However in the WInterfaceTable documentation there is no specific sentence (as far as I can see) saying that this is not possible. Have you found one?

Comment: I think that Apple usually explains what is possible without a very long list specifying what is not possible. Such a list could be very, very long. :)  When I study the documentation, I do not see any method to achieve the functionality that you desire.

Comment: PS: My app would also profit very much if this was possible. Let's hope that it will be possible soon. :-)

Comment: have you tried implementing a custom control that mimics the behaviour? I guess it should be possible to add EaseIn/EaseOut transitions to them..

Comment: maybe they will introduce this in iOS 9. Apple says that they plan to make Watch apps independent from Phone apps and that's probably what iOS 9 will be also about.

Comment: Is this still not possible in WatchOS 3 / iOS 10?